# Is $ f^{-1}(X\cap Y)=f^{-1}(X)\cap f^{-1}(Y)$ for all subsets $X, Y$ of $\Bbb R\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

For a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, we need to find which of the following statements is/are correct

(1) $ f(X\cap Y)=f(X)\cap f(Y)$ for all subsets $X,Y$ of $\,\Bbb R.$

(2) $ f^{-1}(X\cap Y)=f^{-1}(X)\cap f^{-1}(Y)$ for all subsets $X,Y$ of $\,\Bbb R.$

The first statement is obviously incorrect as LHS is a subset of RHS but what about the second statement? Please help.

Comment: Inverse image preserves absolutely everything: intersections, unions, disjoint unions, complement. The proof is just straight from the definition. If you know what an inverse image is, just show a two sided inclusion.

Comment: $(1)$ would be correct if $f$ were injective.

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward: when we say $x \in f^{-1} (A)$, it means that $f (x) \in A$, and vice versa. We can apply that here to show (1):

Let $a \in f^{-1} (X \cap Y)$. Then $f (a) \in X \cap Y$. That is, $f (a) \in X$ and $f (a) \in Y$. The former condition means $a \in f^{-1} (X)$, and the latter means $a \in f^{-1} (Y)$. Thus, $a \in f^{-1} (X) \cap f^{-1} (Y)$.

Now let $a \in f^{-1} (X) \cap f^{-1} (Y)$. This means that $a \in f^{-1} (X)$ and $a \in f^{-1} (Y)$. The former condition means $f (a) \in X$, and the latter means $f (a) \in Y$. Therefore, $f (a) \in X \cap Y$, so $a \in f^{-1} (X \cap Y)$.